# Пространство имен в XML (xmlns:mvc)

Tags: xml, namespace, xsd, sap

Изучаю новый фреймоврк(SAPUI5), в нем используется представление в виде XML, прочитал немного про XML:

xmlns:mvc - это же пространоство имен mvc, которые используется в корне проекта, но чуть выше используется xmlns - просто без префикса. Обьясните пожалуйста какое пространство имен будет у дочерних элементов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Немного не понял вопрос.
С помощью XMLNS задаем пространство имен.

```
xmlns="sap.m" //будет NS по умелчанию
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
```

Т.е. Это будет развернуто в:

lable -> sap.m.lable

button -> sap.m.button

mvc:view -> sap.ui.core.mvc.view

xmlns:html в рамках XMLView смысла не имеет.